# outerWidth() doubled on dynamically loaded buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-load float-right" data-modal="http://tiger.dev/users/create" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Create">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

And I have the following jQuery code to change the html to a loading icon when clicked:

```
// show loader and disable button second click
$(document).on('click', '.btn-load', function (event) {
    if ($(this).attr('data-original-html')) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.preventBubble();
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('width', $(this).outerWidth());
        $(this).attr('data-original-html', $(this).html());
        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    }

    console.log($(this).outerWidth());
});

// restore load button after ajax is complete
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $('[data-original-html]').each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).attr('data-original-html'));
        $(this).removeAttr('data-original-html');
        $(this).css('width', 'auto');
    });
});
```

Now this works fine for most buttons. The console is showing a `outerWidth()` of `38.5625` in this example.

However, I also have a server-side datatable which renders buttons in each row, so the buttons are generated dynamically. Here is the example code for one of those buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-load" data-modal="http://tiger.dev/users/update/1" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Update">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

The console log for `outerWidth()` is showing about double the actual width in the console e.g. `65.7188` for this button. This is a problem because I want all buttons to maintain the same width when changed to the loading icon. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: The only difference between the 2 is `float-right` class. Start there, as it seems unsalvageable at this point. My guess is that without `float: right`, your button has some weird styles affecting it's width / display property. Either that, or some styles on the parent (datatable?) affecting the buttons inside it.

Comment: Can you include a link to the working site or demo?